# google api not working for geolocation

Tags: javascript, api

i have found a script for geolocation resolve with google
in this code there is a key that is 86 char long

i have opened a google api key for the gmail of the website
it is a short key (only 39 chars)

i then changed the key and run the code.

i get the resolve country location that i need.
i then tried from another ip location (at home) and one with a proxy sever and didn't get any thing

i'm not sure if the api key i'm using is set for public or not- how do i check that?
do i have to pay for using it or can be used only with the free 25,000 request per day?

the code i have tried is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key="></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function geoTest() {

    if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {

        var latitude = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
        var longitude = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
        var city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
        var country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
        var country_code = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
        var region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;

        var text = 'Your Location<br /><br />Latitude: ' + latitude + '<br />Longitude: ' + longitude + '<br />City: ' + city + '<br />Country: ' + country + '<br />Country Code: ' + country_code + '<br />Region: ' + region;

    } else {

        var text = 'Google was not able to detect your location';

    }

    document.write(text);
}

geoTest();

</script>
```

Comment: If you open URL `http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=` directly in your browser what the 13th line says?

Comment: in line 13 it says: null, but give me the location for the computer with the IP i used when opened the api for the email account

Comment: Did you used a laptop? Could it be a cache issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the geolocation is not reliable
See Philippe's answer here [Is google.loader.clientlocation still supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195837/is-google-loader-clientlocation-still-supported)