# Is Geocoder Still Working For Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hi I would like to know if Geocoder is still working? It does not seems to reactive when I initialize new google.maps.geocoder(); My purpose here is to obtain the location address from the latitude and longitude.

Alert A and B is working. Stops at Alert C.

```
$('#btn').click(function initialize() {
            alert("A");
            var loc = {};
            alert("B");
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            alert("C");
            if(google.loader.ClientLocation) {
                alert("D");
                loc.lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
                loc.lng = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);
                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        alert(results[0]['formatted_address']);
                    };
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `alert(google.loader.ClientLocation);` after `alert("C");` and say what u got. explain y u using `google.loader.ClientLocation` and do u have lat and lng before calling this function?

Comment: Return null. Why is this so? I have included the jsapis.js file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195837/is-google-loader-clientlocation-still-supported

Comment: @Bryan Learn   Is my answer ok to get address from Lat,Lng?

Comment: @Lashmana Kumar, it seems like it is not able to load the ClientLocation

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get address from lat, lng. Click on marker to show address. Its alternate way to do ur job.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA7IZt-36CgqSGDFK8pChUdQXFyKIhpMBY&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;
        var latlng;
        var infowindow;

        $(document).ready(function() {

        });

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4230, 98.7372),   // Coimbatore = (11.0168445, 76.9558321)
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var latlngStr = $('#address').val().split(",");
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);

            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            map.setCenter(latlng);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': event.latLng }, function(results, status) {
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                });

                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <label>
        Lat, Lng:
    </label>
    <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="10.9435131, 76.9383790" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="initialize()" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```