# Does Google Have a Geo IP Service?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Does Google have an API to do geocoding from ip address to latitude longitude?  Similar to MaxMind. I have looked into their places api:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/
```

And I have used Maxmind with success,

```
http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing
```

But does Google offer ip to lat long services?

Comment: This question was closed so I can't officially answer, but Google does offer a specific service that will convert IP to Lat Long. A POST to `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY` with no fields will fallback to using IP address.

Answer (score 14):

Strictly just f.y.i., google's loader https://developers.google.com/loader/ which you would load with a simple script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

does store info about their best guess about a users location, presumably done via i.p. lookup, within google.loader.ClientLocation object. In fact here's a fiddle example showing your own (supposed) location with a Marker http://jsfiddle.net/pTfM5/2/

It's horribly inaccurate for me, shows me to be an entire state and a couple hundred miles away from where I really am. ipinfodb and ip2location as suggested by Michael C. are a bit more accurate, they show me just two thirds as far away as reality than googles loader does, still off by a long ways.

Maxmind is much better though, only off by about 20 miles

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill have to look into that.  I havent used the jsapi before, but I've been meaning to.

Comment: The JS fiddle does not work anymore.

Comment: yeah, `google.loader.ClientLocation` does not exist anymore -- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195837/is-google-loader-clientlocation-still-supported) question related to its deprecation

Comment: The JS fiddle doesn't always work